# Putting curly braces on the same line in C when autocompleting snippets with VSCode Intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, curly-braces, vscode-snippets

I am a long time Atom user. I finally decided to switch over to VS Code but there is one thing that if I cannot solve I am going back to Atom. I am a hardware engineer so I primarily write C code. I am looking for a way to fix the IntelliSense snippet code formatting.

For example, when I start typing `while` and press Tab to autocomplete, I get this:

```
while (/* condition */)
{
   /* code */
}
```

I am looking for a way for the autocomplete to put the curly brace on the same line as such:

```
while (/* condition */) {
   /* code */
}
```

From what I can tell, the only way to change this is to edit the default snippets that come with the C/C++ extension. I have tried going to `~/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-1.2.2` (I am on a Mac) but to no avail. There is no snippets folder.

I have also tried adding

```
"C_Cpp.vcFormat.newLine.beforeOpenBrace.block": "sameLine",
"C_Cpp.vcFormat.newLine.beforeOpenBrace.function": "sameLine",
"C_Cpp.vcFormat.newLine.beforeOpenBrace.lambda": "sameLine",
"C_Cpp.vcFormat.newLine.beforeOpenBrace.namespace": "sameLine",
"C_Cpp.vcFormat.newLine.beforeOpenBrace.type": "sameLine",
"C_Cpp.clang_format_style": "WebKit",
"C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "WebKit"
```

to the `settings.json` file but, again, nothing.

This is incredibly important to fix for me so if you have any solutions I am all ears. Thank you.

Comment: these snippets are not that complex, write your own versions in the custom c snippets file, start all these snippets with a unique prefix like: `cwhile`, `cfor`, `cswitch`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create a custom snippet. See: [Create your own snippets](https://Create%20your%20own%20snippets).

To “replace” the existing snippet, you’ll need to hide it from IntelliSense. See: [Can I remove snippets from IntelliSense?](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_can-i-remove-snippets-from-intellisense)

RIP Atom